Is there a DEX on solana devnet?
On solauncher.org I can create a market and liquidity on OpenBook and raydium in devnet. Is there any DEX operational on devnet to play a market for customer tests?
Or is there any OTC-style frontend supporting bid/ask for tokens on devnet availible for self-hosting?
